# Gradle Sync failed due to groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to Android Studio. I am trying to make a new project.

But it always says that Gradle Sync failed and throws the exception:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property
> 'com' for root project 'Assn1' of type org.gradle.api.Project.    at
> org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have initiated the task but not defined it in file

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException this exception occurred when gradle not able to find a property. Gradle check these properties in sequence as below if not find out throw this exception.

1 - gradle.properties
2 - System environment variables
3 - command-line arguments to execute the build script
4 - build.gradle

You can refer to solve these issues from the link below https://facingissuesonit.com/2020/04/29/groovy-lang-missingpropertyexception-could-not-get-unknown-property-a-for-task-b-of-type-org-gradle-api-defaulttask/